# this is showing identatio error ...why

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def snippet_list(request):
    """
    list all the code snippets ,or create a new snippet.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        snippet = Snippet.object.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many = True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data =data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(serializer.data,status =201)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors,status=400)
```

Comment: Were the `"""` lines meant to be a comment?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing tabs and spaces:

[image: indentation highlight]

The lines indicate tabs, the dots spaces. Python expands tabs to every 8th column.

Don't mix tabs and spaces, convert your tabs back to spaces and configure your editor to only use spaces for indentation.

You can configure most editors to use spaces *only* for indentation; this is what the [Python styleguide (PEP 8)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends:

> ### Tabs or Spaces?
>
> Never mix tabs and spaces.
>
> The most popular way of indenting Python is with spaces only. The second-most popular way is with tabs only. Code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces exclusively. When invoking the Python command line interpreter with the -t option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs and spaces. When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options are highly recommended!
>
> For new projects, spaces-only are strongly recommended over tabs. Most editors have features that make this easy to do.